# Why is bw.nrd0() function and bw="nrd0" showing different results of density plot?

Tags: density-function, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

According to `density` function documentation in R [(source)](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/density), they use `"nrd0"` as default setting. However, when I tried `bw.nrd0(x)` [[(source)](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/bandwidth.html); `x` is vector of my data], the two gave quite significant different level of smoothness in my plot (or bandwidth). Does `bw.nrd0()` function perform differently than the default settings of `density()` in R?

sample code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x_axis)) + 

     geom_density(aes(color = category), bw=bw.nrd0(data$x_axis))
```

I think it's probably because of `bw=bw.nrd0()` function applies not per category but as entirity?

Practically, what I'm asking is, how to select optimal bandwith for `geom_density` which involves categories?

Answer (score 1):

If you do (from the help page example)

```
plot(density(precip, n = 1000))
rug(precip)
lines(density(precip,bw="nrd0"),col=2,lty=2,lwd=3)
```

you get two identical curves superimposed. You also get the same curve from

```
> bw.nrd0(precip)
[1] 3.847892
> lines(density(precip, bw=3.847892),col=4,lty=3,lwd=2)
```

I think you need to provide a reproducible example if you're saying they are different.